# Run-time error '1004' on closing Excel vba 2013

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I'm having a run-time error 1004 on closing the excel sheet. Through my research, most of error 1004 happen when the users are trying to copy the sheet by macro or closing the sheet by macro.

In my case, the error appears even when I close the developer tab and create a new excel file. Some resources I found online include the [You may receive a "Run-time error 1004" error message when you programmatically set a large array string to a range in Excel 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818808) and some other forum posts. However none of them is applicable in my case since I'm trying to close the file by the 'x' button. Please let me know if should describe the question more accurately. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Davesexcel, this is the problem.. Even if I create a new file (no codes, macros and etc.), the error is still there